# SQL Error : USE `most`; SELECT `item_name`, SUM(`stock_invent`) AS `Total Items` FROM inventories GROUP BY `item_name

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to print out the list total of items by SQL. It works well on *phpmyadmin* but not in Dreamweaver. I dont know what is wrong with my SQL. Anyone can help me?

```
mysql_select_db($database_dbcon, $dbcon);

$query_Recordset1 = "USE `most`; SELECT `item_name`, SUM(`stock_invent`) AS `Total Items` FROM inventories GROUP BY `item_name`";

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $dbcon) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

i got this kind of messages :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT `item_name`, SUM(`stock_invent`) AS `Total Items` FROM
>   inventories GROUP ' at line 1

Comment: Try using a single quote instead of a backtick for the column alias.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this multi query syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `use` command is used in phpMyAdmin (as well as in mysql's command line tool) to select the database you want to run queries against. In PHP, you should not need it - that's what `mysql_select_db` is for:

```
mysql_select_db('most', $dbcon);

$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT `item_name`, SUM(`stock_invent`) AS `Total Items` FROM inventories GROUP BY `item_name`";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_select_db('most', $dbcon);

$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT item_name, SUM(stock_invent) AS Total Items FROM inventories GROUP BY item_name ";

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $dbcon) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```